# Vue.js update contents in div dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, rest, vue.js

I am attempting to do a SPA using Vue.js but unfortunately I know almost nothing about it, I followed a tutorial and got something up and running. This should hopefully be relatively simple!

I'm trying to create a simple page that:

- Does a REST API call and pulls some JSON
- A list with links of a particular field in the list of results is displayed on the left side of the screen

(I've managed until here)

Now I would like to be able to click on one of the links and see on the right side of the screen the value of another field for the same record.

For instance, suppose my JSON is:

```
{
   "jokes":{
      [
         "setup":"setup1",
         "punchline":"punchline1"
      ],
      [
         "setup":"setup2",
         "punchline":"punchline2"
      ],
      [
         "setup":"setup3",
         "punchline":"punchline3"
      ]
   }
}
```

So in my screen I would see:

```
setup1
setup2
setup3
```

So if I click in setup1 I see punchline1, setup2 displays punchline2 and so on.

Here is my code - I'm basically trying to display the punchline in the `moduleinfo` div. I realise the current solution does not work. I've been searching but can't find any similar examples. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="module-list">
      <input type="text" v-model.trim="search" placeholder="Search"/>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li class="modules" v-for="value in modulesList" :key="value.id">
            <a href="#">{{ value.setup }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="moduleinfo">
      <h2>Module info</h2>
      <!-- <p>{{ value.punchline }}</p> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Home',

  data: function(){
    return {
      jokes: [],
      search : ""
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getModules();
  },

  methods: {
    getModules() {
      var self = this

      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/joke/search',
        params: {term: 'car'},
        headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-key': '...',
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
      };

      axios.request(options)
        .then(response => {
            self.jokes = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
      });
    }
  },

  computed: {
    modulesList: function () {
      var jokes = this.jokes.body;
      var search = this.search;

      if (search){
        jokes = jokes.filter(function(value){
          if(value.setup.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
            return jokes;
          }
        })
      }
      return jokes;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was building a sample Single File Component in my Vue 2 CLI app, and when I came back to post it, Ryoko had already answered the question with the same approach that I recommend, adding a new property to track showing the punchline.

Since I already built it, I figured that I might as well post my component, which does change the layout, using a table instead of a list, but the functionality works.

```
<template>
  <div class="joke-list">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>SETUP</th>
              <th>PUNCHLINE</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(joke, index) in jokes" :key="index">
              <td>
                <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="getPunchline(index)">{{ joke.setup }}</a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span v-if="joke.showPunchline">{{ joke.punchline }}</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        jokes: [
          {
            setup: "setup1",
            punchline: "punchline1"
          },
          {
            setup: "setup2",
            punchline: "punchline2"
          },
          {
            setup: "setup3",
            punchline: "punchline3"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getPunchline(index) {
        this.jokes[index].showPunchline = true;
      },
      addPropertyToJokes() {
        // New property must be reactive
        this.jokes.forEach( joke => this.$set(joke, 'showPunchline', false) );
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.addPropertyToJokes();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new property inside the data object and then make a new method to set it accordingly when you click the `<a>` tag. Have a look at the code below, it was a copy of your current solution, edited & simplified to show the addition that I made to make it easier for you to find it.

The `select` method will insert the object of the clicked joke to the `selectedJoke` so you can render it below the Module Info.

Because it's defaults to `null`, and it might be `null` or `undefined`, you have to add `v-if` to the attribute to check wether there is a value or not so you don't get error on the console.

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="module-list">
      <input type="text" v-model.trim="search" placeholder="Search"/>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li class="modules" v-for="value in modulesList" :key="value.id">
            <a href="#" @click.prevent="select(value)">{{ value.setup }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="moduleinfo">
      <h2>Module info</h2>
      <p v-if="selectedJoke">{{ selectedJoke.punchline }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Home',

  data: function(){
    return {
      jokes: [],
      search : "",
      selectedJoke: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    select(joke) {
      this.selectedJoke = joke;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```